# How to make ActiveX object discoverable via navigator.plugins?

Tags: javascript, windows, registry, activex, internet-explorer-11

I'm currently working with an ActiveX control, and I'm trying to make it discoverable via navigator.plugins, so I could re-use the same detection logic for both this ActiveX object and a FireFox plug-in with the same functionality.

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948(v=vs.85).aspx) lists a number of registry keys ActiveX installer has to add in order for it to appear in `navigator.plugins`, as well as some properties it should expose; however either the list is incomplete, or that page forgets to mention some extra thing that ActiveX control should do/have.

The ActiveX control is discoverable via `new ActiveXObject( 'myPluginId' )`, so I would suspect that the problem is as simple as some missing reg entry, but which one?

I tried installing Adobe's Flash ActiveX and checked which keys that one create, but couldn't find anything different from what I'm doing, apart from mime-type registration in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\MIME\Database\Content Type\` (which I added for my plugin as well without much luck).

NavigatorPluginsList key looks like this right now:

```
Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\NavigatorPluginsList
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   4/21/2014 - 4:40 PM


Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\NavigatorPluginsList\MyPlugin.ie_api.1
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   4/21/2014 - 4:40 PM
Value 0
  Name:            application/x-my-plugin-mimetype
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            


Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\NavigatorPluginsList\Shockwave Flash
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   4/21/2014 - 3:21 PM
Value 0
  Name:            application/x-shockwave-flash
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please include either a screenshot of your registry editor showing the configuration of the `NavigatorPluginsList` key, or a textual dump generated by an export of that key.

Comment: Hi Eric, I updated the issue with the dump you requested. Thanks!

Comment: @alemikh: I've sent mail to the IE engineering team on this one, because even after implementing the proper keys in the `MIME` registry key and ensuring that the DLL has the appropriate `FileVersionInformation` I still cannot make the API work properly.

Comment: Ah. Well, good to know that I'm not the only one with this problem. Please let me know once you get an answer on this. Thanks!

Comment: Even if you add an entry in the NavigatorPluginsList and refer it to an existing MIME-type (e.g. application/x-silverlight) instead of creating your own type (?) its still doesn't work.  navigator.plugins will still not 'find' your plugin .....      =:-O((